# setting global allocation limit HANA

Tags: memory, hana

When I try to set the global allocation limit for HANA I get the error message

> Transaction rolled back by internal error:exception 70000000:ste:: exception type file system manage /usr/sap.../global.ini ;Reason Write error

I assume I do not have the privilege to write in the `global.ini` file. Can I edit the `global.ini` file with the DB OS user? How can it be resolved? Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked whether the file system where the .ini file is stored is full by any chance? The file permissions should be fine and the error message would be different if they weren't.

Comment: No it's not full there is 46 GB available out of 50 GB.But my log file system is kind of full.Will it be a problem?

Comment: Writing to the ini file should never lead to an error. Can you write to the file with VIM ? (it's a text file)

Comment: No I cannot it shows  **E:514:write error (file system full?)** and I found it is writing a new file global.ini.new which is empty.

Comment: In that case, I'd say: check again, if the filesystem _at that location_ is actually not full: 
free -h .

Comment: It should be a comment, not answer.